# App click to splash screen taking 3 seconds. Need to reduce time

Tags: ios, xcode, launching-application

In my project i found, From App Icon  click to Splash Screen is taking time upto 3 seconds. (Before going to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).So i create an empty project without single piece of code written from my side. Then i tested the same problem with empty project still the issue remains. I have run the project using developer/enterprise Profile and XCode 7.3.1.

The Other  Applications downloaded from App store, this issue is not found. They are launching within 1 second.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618163/displaying-splash-screen-for-longer-than-default-seconds and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070219/how-make-the-splash-screen-last-longer-in-a-xcode-project

Comment: It is taking 3 secs to show splash screen Need to reduce the time to open the app. After clicking the ios App, it is not opening.