# xcode 6 - change default launch screen display time

Tags: xcode, xcode6, delay, splash-screen, launch-screen

In a new Xcode 6 project, a default `LaunchScreen.xib` file is created that is displayed for a brief time when the app starts. How can I alter the time of the display e.g. display it for 5 seconds?

Comment: you mean like this topic I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511353/change-iphone-splash-screen-time

Comment: Create custom splash screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `NSThread`:

```
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)];
```

You can put this code in to first line of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

For example, display screen for 4 seconds.

File: AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

  /*this will pause main thread for x interval seconds. 
  put on the top of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, so it will not 
  proceed to show window until sleep interval is finished.*/

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4]; //add 4 seconds longer.
   //other code....
}
```

Comment: I was looking for some settings in Xcode. But this works as well! Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I hope it does not get my app rejected.